# How to do rolling window count on time series with multi-index?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation

I have this dataframe:

```
ID      Date                          Received      
000     2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00     True
        2018-01-01 06:24:44+00:00     True
        2018-01-03 16:24:45+00:00     False
        2018-01-13 20:00:00+00:00     True
        2018-01-13 23:00:00+00:00     True
        2018-01-25 22:30:55+00:00     True 
        2018-01-26 00:30:55+00:00     False

111     2018-01-01 12:00:00+00:00     True
        2018-01-02 15:00:45+00:00     True
        2018-01-04 00:00:00+00:00     True
```

Is there a way to do a rolling window count of the number of True values in the Received column for a 7 day period and grouped by ID? I tried using the df.rolling('7D').count() but it returns an error.

I was looking for something like this:

```
ID      Date range                                                Count     
000     2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 - 2018-01-07 00:00:00+00:00     2
        2018-01-08 20:00:00+00:00 - 2018-01-14 00:00:00+00:00     2
        2018-01-15 22:30:55+00:00 - 2018-01-21 20:00:00+00:00     0
        2018-01-22 22:30:55+00:00 - 2018-01-28 20:00:00+00:00     1

111     2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 - 2018-01-07 00:00:00+00:00     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and specify the frequency:

```
df.groupby(["ID", pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1W')])["Received"].sum()
```

Full answer:

```
# Count the number of True per week per ID
out = df.groupby(["ID", pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1W')])["Received"] \
        .sum() \
        .to_frame() \
        .reset_index() \
        .rename(columns={"Received": "Count"})
print(out)
#     ID                      Date  Count
# 0  000 2018-01-07 00:00:00+00:00    2.0
# 1  000 2018-01-14 00:00:00+00:00    2.0
# 2  000 2018-01-28 00:00:00+00:00    1.0
# 3  111 2018-01-07 00:00:00+00:00    3.0


# Fill missing date ranges
def fill_date_range(df):
    dates = pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max(), freq="1W")
    return df.set_index("Date") \
             .reindex(dates)[['Count']] \
             .fillna(0)

# Fill missing date range             
out = out.groupby(by="ID").apply(fill_date_range) \
        .reset_index()  \
        .rename(columns={"level_1": "Date"})
print(out)
#     ID                      Date  Count
# 0  000 2018-01-07 00:00:00+00:00    2.0
# 1  000 2018-01-14 00:00:00+00:00    2.0
# 2  000 2018-01-21 00:00:00+00:00    0.0
# 3  000 2018-01-28 00:00:00+00:00    1.0
# 4  111 2018-01-07 00:00:00+00:00    3.0

# Add date range interval as string
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
out["Date_expected"] = out.Date.dt.strftime(format) + " - " + (out.Date + pd.Timedelta(weeks=-1)).dt.strftime(format)
print(out)
#     ID                      Date  Count                              Date_expected
# 0  000 2018-01-07 00:00:00+00:00    2.0  2018-01-07 00:00:00 - 2017-12-31 00:00:00
# 1  000 2018-01-14 00:00:00+00:00    2.0  2018-01-14 00:00:00 - 2018-01-07 00:00:00
# 2  000 2018-01-21 00:00:00+00:00    0.0  2018-01-21 00:00:00 - 2018-01-14 00:00:00
# 3  000 2018-01-28 00:00:00+00:00    1.0  2018-01-28 00:00:00 - 2018-01-21 00:00:00
# 4  111 2018-01-07 00:00:00+00:00    3.0  2018-01-07 00:00:00 - 2017-12-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: Sorry I have another question, is there a way to count all of the values within the range including the False ones?

Comment: Feel free to open a new question if required. Happy coding :-)